# Test Error with :create Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

All assertions pass, but I'm getting an error:

1) Error:

```
test_should_perform_user_login(SessionsControllerTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `create' for StoriesController:Class
```

Here's the code for the test:

```
def test_should_perform_user_login                                                                                                    
  post :create, :login => 'patrick', :password => 'sekrit'                                                                            
  assert_redirected_to stories_path                                                                                                   
  assert_equal users(:patrick).id, session[:user_id]                                                                                  
  assert_equal users(:patrick), assigns(:current_user)  
end
```

Here is where I define the create method in `sessions_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @current_user = User.find_by_login_and_password(params[:login], params[:password])

    if @current_user
        session[:user_id] = @current_user.id
        if session[:return_to]
            redirect_to session[:return_to]
            session[:return_to] = nil
        else
            redirect_to stories_path
        end
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

does this help?

I'm reading the book, '[Simply Rails 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/rails2/)'.

Comment: Is there a `create` method? Why is the `SessionsControllerTest` class referring to the `StoriesController`?

Comment: I do have a create method. I have no idea what's going on with the `SessionsControllerTest` class referring to the `StoriesController`

Comment: You might have to provide more info, then; looks like something's hosed up in either the `stories_path`, spec layout, etc.

Comment: What more info can I post? I'm still stumped here.. I've got the project up on github [here](https://github.com/IAMRYO/shovell) too.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cloned. Um... What version of Rails are you using? Right now it looks like Rails 2.0--that's a ***very*** old version. Unless you have a *really* good reason, please don't use it. Also, what version of Ruby? And RSpec? Just setting things up to even run this just feels wrong.

Comment: Dave, thanks for cloning.  I am using Rails 2 and Ruby 1.8.6... I know this is terrible, but all the tutorials in the book were written using Rails 2.  I tried working through with current versions and I just don't know enough about the language to have bridged the gaps myself, so I used all the same versions as the author.  The tests are in the native test suite... No Rspec.  I'm away from my dev laptop, but will send along my gem list in a few hours.

Comment: Ruby 1.8.6 with
actionmailer (2.0.2), actionpack (2.0.2), activerecord (2.0.2), ctiveresource (2.0.2), activesupport (2.0.2), rails (2.0.2), rake (0.9.2), sqlite3-ruby (1.2.1)

Comment: I have to warn you, Rails has changed a _lot_ since then. If I can get a working environment set up I'll take a look.

Comment: I appreciate it. I know it's vastly differect and plan to follow up with the PragProg RSpec  book,  then their Agile dev  book.  Gotta start somewhere.

Comment: By the way, I'd urge you to use more blank lines between things, like methods, "chunks" of HTML, etc.--it goes a long way towards making things readable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biggest error fixed.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `create' for StoriesController:Class
```

This comes from the `before_filter` call where you left a `:` (colon) off of the method symbols array.

The next error was in `application.rb`; its error was:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `redirect_to_new_session_path'
```

There's an extra underscore between the `redirect_to` method and its argument, `new_session_path`.

Next was a bogus selector in the stores test. Last I'm leaving as an exercise for the reader :) (Hint: there are two problems.)